# If $E/F\simeq G$ holds, does one have $E/G\simeq F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a $K$-vector space, and $F,G\subset E$ two subvector spaces.

> **Question 1.** If $E/F\simeq G$ holds, does one also have $E/G\simeq F$ ?

That clearly holds if $E$ is finite dimensional over $K$, but what in general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False for infinite-dimensional vector spaces. It’s Hilbert’s hotel all over again: Let your basis $\{b_i\}$ for $E$ be indexed by the positive integers, then $\langle b_0\rangle=F$ has $E/F\cong E$.

Answer (score 5):

It can be false in the infinite-dimensional case. Consider for example $E=K[X]=G$ and $F=\langle X,X^3,X^5,\dots\rangle $. Then
$$E/F\cong K[X^2]\cong G$$
but
$$E/G=0\ncong F.$$